# how can i validate in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

how to make my save button save only if it validates that a field is numeric if not, show message?

```
{ name: 'fechaHoraRegistro', index: 'fechaHoraRegistro', width: 90, editable: true, editoptions: {
            size: 15, maxlengh: 10,
                dataInit: function (es) {
                    $(es).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });                            
                },
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'horaRegistro', index: 'horaRegistro', width: 0, editable: true, hidden: false, edittype: 'text', editoptions: {
                size: 15, maxlengh: 10,
                dataInit: function (element) {
                    $(element).keyup(function () {
                        var val1 = element.value;
                        var num = new Number(val1);
                        if (isNaN(num))
                        { alert("Ingresar solo numeros"); }
                    })
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the build in validation. For this purpose you will need to use editrules. More you can find here in [Guriddo jqGrid documentation.](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#editrules)

In you case it is simple:

```
{
    name: 'horaRegistro', index: 'horaRegistro', width: 0, editable: true, hidden: false, 
    edittype: 'text', 
    editoptions: {
        size: 15, 
        maxlengh: 10,
    },
    editrules : { 
       number : true
    }
},
```

You also can set min max and other limitations.